# Show HTML select value

Tags: html, select, html-select

I want show all select box values like first image [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wds91.png). But firefox show like second image[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TfkY.png). how to solve this

```css
#mySelect
{
 width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#mySelect option
{
 float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:inline;
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="4">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
     <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this question about how to show the select value or on how to solve the layout issue? You can't have 2 questions in 1.

Comment: i see its a layout problem

Comment: No its not layout problem first image chrome browser show the values correctly. Second image firefox browser show the values incorrectly. so how to solve the issue in firefox

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend using flexbox instead of float.

Css tricks has [a great guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on how to use flexbox

Something like (not tested)

```
#mySelect {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: That has to do with the style on your `#mySelect option`

Comment: Maybe remove the `display: inline` and add a width of 20%?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change `display:inline` on your `#mySelect option` to `display:inline-block` that might give you what you're looking for. If that doesn't work, you could also play with the [word-wrap CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

It's worth noting that you will have a different appearance in other browsers... (I left the code snippets in as proof that I reproduced your example exactly)

In Chrome it looks like this:
[image: chrome screen capture]

and in Safari (the default browser on Mac OS) it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this article on Mozilla.org (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms)- some form widgets (like the select element) are difficult or impossible to style without encountering browser issues (like you did with firefox)

You can skip over most of the article but note the section where it starts with "Dealing with the select nightmare" - They show some ideas to resolve your issue there.

To quote the article: "If you want to gain full control over form widgets, you have no choice but to rely on JavaScript."

The following article can also help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_build_custom_form_widgets